# java android server and client on same device in 2 applications

Tags: android, sockets, ipc

I have 2 android applications one which is server (starts android.net.ServerSocket)
and the other is client. connects to a predefined port via android.net.Socket
ServerApp start and stops server depending on its lifecylce (onResume/onPause)
ClientApp starts ForegroundService and continues trying to establish connection.

Currently I'm receiveing communication refused Exception.

Is there any restrictions on such communication? (e.g same keys to sign 2 apps) or something like that?
What should be my main points to look at, while fixing this issue.?

UPDATE:
Both of these apps are on the same device

Thanks to @blackapps: Following solution implemented

```
  private fun InetAddress.connect(
    port: Int,
    connectionTimeout: Int = SOCKET_CONNECTION_TIMEOUT_MILLIS,
    onConnect: Socket.() -> Unit = {}
) {
    val newSocket = Socket()
    val socketAddress = if(context.getMyIp()?.hostAddress == hostAddress){
        InetSocketAddress("127.0.0.1", port)
    } else {
        InetSocketAddress(this, port)
    }
    newSocket.connect(socketAddress, connectionTimeout)

    newSocket.use { it.onConnect() }
}
```

But the error still persists:
Connection to /192.168.0.22 is stopped due to failed to connect to localhost/127.0.0.1 (port 48564) from /127.0.0.1 (port 55828) after 5000ms: isConnected failed: ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused)

UPDATE 2:

```
 serverSocket = ServerSocket(DATA_STREAM_PORT)
            serverSocket.soTimeout = DEFAULT_TIMEOUT
            serverSocket.use { server ->
                while (!server.isClosed) {
                    val client = server.accept()
                    ...do smth
                }
             }
```

Comment: No restrictions. It's possible. Has nothing to do with keys or signing.

Comment: `communication refused Exception.` ? Never heard of that exception.

Comment: failed to connect to /192.168.0.22 (port 48564) from /192.168.0.22 (port 41822) after 5000ms: isConnected failed: ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused)

Comment: Indeed: connection refused. Not communication refused. You should use ip 127.0.0.1 instead.

Comment: Thanks, @blackapps
I'm using the NSD service to retrieve the address and port to connect so ServerApp is registering the service ClientApp starts discovery.
I'm getting the InetAddress object as a result of this discovery. 
How do I know if the address is local to this device to replace it with 127.0.0.1 .
InetAddress has multiple methods
isAnyLocalAddress
isLinkLocalAddress
and  more, all of them say false for my specific case.?

Comment: You said that both server and client run on the same device. So then use 127.0.0.1 as ip. There is nothing to search then. Ni discovery needed on same device.

Comment: It's one of the cases, sometimes it's 2 devices. 
For the current mode that I'm working on it's 1 device running both server and client.
That's why I don't want to break the existing logic behind service discovery
especially because it's working, so how can I understand from InetAddress if it's been from same device or not?

Comment: The client can determine its own ip too. So if they are equal... Just put 127.0.0.1 in it to test.

Comment: connection to /192.168.0.22 is stopped due to failed to connect to localhost/127.0.0.1 (port 48564) from /127.0.0.1 (port 55828) after 5000ms: isConnected failed: ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused)
still not working

Comment: Its time you show your server code.

Comment: I've added sample of my server code to the question. It's pretty straightforward.
Thereisn't any logs on server side app which would confirm something trying to connect.

Comment: I have no idea why it would not work. INTERNET permission?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249908/discussion-between---and-blackapps).

Comment: No i will not chat.

Comment: ok, so INTERNET permission is there.
I'm completely out of idea what's wrong, and even though I see there is LocalSocket, and LocalServerSocket which would probably suit me better, but I really don't want to break existing fucntionality , and rewrite server/client completely to support both singledevice and 2 devices approach.

I expected it to be  pretty simple to start server on 1 app and then connect to it through other app Socket as one of IPC approaches.

Comment: You are not binding your server to an ip i hope.

Comment: I'm using contructor of server socket which has a PORT in constructor . it says,, that it creates a server socket bound to specified port.

Comment: Also I'm not using ServerSocket constructor with three params (where third is InetAddress bindAddr) if that's helpful to my question.